# Add extra number in ordered array

Tags: php, arrays, insert

Which is the best way to insert a new number in an already ascendant ordered array?

```
$new_number = 6;
$old_array = array(1,3,4,5,7,8,10);

// $new_array must be 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
$old_array = array(1,3,4,5,7,8,10);
$old_array[] = 6;
sort($old_array);

/* Notes:
   sort() will actually change the array which you pass to it
   don't do:   $old_array = sort($old_array);
*/
```

Comment: Sort did the trick, the Notes is really very important, I tested. All the best!

Comment: Thanks, you too! I'm sure you've figured this out by now but the same rule applies for the other sort functions as well such as `ksort()`, `krsort()`, `arsort()`, etc...

Answer (score 5):

Why not just add it and sort it again ?

```
$new_number = 6;
$old_array = array(1,3,4,5,7,8,10);
array_push($old_array,$new_number);
sort($old_array);
```