# Please help debug some basic php

Tags: php

Im doing this PHP code and trying to get started with using OOP in PHP. So the first lesson uses this piece of code. For some reason when I execute it it doesn't work and gives an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   /web/com/139472683619280/main.php on line 20

```
<?php
    class MyClass{

      public $hello = "Hello World";
      public function result(){
        echo $this->hello;

        }

    }
    $objectMyClass = new MyClass();
    $objecyMyClass->result();
  ?>
```

I was hoping someone could give me some insight as to why I am getting this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to use a title that properly summarizes your problem. Thanks

Comment: Will do. Im new and only getting started here ;).

Comment: @user3410094, Get a good IDE and you can easily find these errors on your own.

Comment: Im using coda2 on the mac, but it did not recognise the typo for some reason. Im still getting used to it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$objecyMyClass->result();
```

Should be:

```
$objectMyClass->result();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo there  .. It is object .. not objecy :P

```
$objectMyClass->result(); // is the correct one
```

A good IDE would have easily found these errors for you. Still using notepad eh ? :)

Comment: `t` is right next to `y` lol - OP must be on a very tiny computer +1 ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Aww mate ty. Notepad still rules !

Comment: My pleasure Shankar. I'm still using Notepad++ - can't afford a better IDE.

Comment: PHPStorm is a good one mate. Go for it..! was using NetBeans earlier.

Comment: I wonder why last posted answers always gets accepted :P , Similar one [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362151/1003917)

Comment: I accepted the the answer because it clearly shows the line of code which is wrong and how to rectify it. Both answers are correct but the chosen answer is a little clearer. This may be irrelevant to experienced coders who can debug their code quickly, but is helpful to less experienced coders or people just getting started.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran You win some, you lose some ;-) You did get 3 upvotes though ;-)